# asp.net 404 error for aspx.cs/js

Tags: asp.net

I migrated an existing application from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 using visual studio 2010.
After migration I noticed, in iis log, a number of 404 errors are there for urls like  xxxxxx.aspx.cs/js for the port 443 as the application uses SSL certificates.

Can you please help in finding answer to below questions :

1. When the url *xxxxxx.aspx.cs/js* is requested from the browser?
2. Why the error 404 is coming for the urls like *xxxxxx.aspx.cs/js* ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `xxxxxx.aspx.cs` cannot be processed by IIS, it is not a valid extension

Comment: the request is not xxxxxx.aspx.cs but xxxxxx.aspx.cs/js

Comment: Murali is correct. A .cs file can not be (or rather, should not be) displayed by IIS. Are users trying to hit this page, or is there a broken link on your site? It could be a malicious user trying to extract details about your site. Are the requests to port 443 some sort of redirect or direct request?

Comment: No users are not trying to hit the url  _xxxxxx.aspx.cs/js_. As this is a behind the filewall application, i do not think of malicious users are trying to access it. With my limited knowledge what I know is _xxxxxx.aspx.cs/js_ request may come when JavaScript are present in the .cs file. In the application we have JavaScript in .cs file.